# Foreach an object in Ko js

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

I'm trying in `Magento 2` to use a foreach on an object to get properties.

I have 2 objects in `ko` `js` and I'm trying to foreach it. 
This is how object looks like in console: 
options()

```
Price: {tooltip: null}

configurable_variation: {options: {…}, tooltip: "some test tooltip"}

__proto__: Object
```

This is how I use it:

```
<div class="abc" data-bind="text:console.log(options())"></div> 
<div class="options-render" data-bind="foreach: { data: options(), as: 'option', noChildContext: true}">
<span class="dev" data-bind="text: console.log(option)"></span>
```

The last console.log instead of retruning Price and configurable_variation its returning the same data that should be foreached.

Comment: Why should the last console.log return price and configurable_variation? You're logging "option", but "option" is nested inside of configurable_variation not the other way around.

Comment: Can you please create a [mcve] with actual value `options()`? Not sure if the `Price` and `configurable_variation` are part of `options()` or of they are separate logs.

Comment: options() contains 2 objects:
1.price
2.configurable_variation()
in the configurable _variation object I have another object called options(). But here the issue is in the foreach the first param is the options( the one who contains the price, and configurable_variation objects). that means that option should be first time price and second time configurable_variation. In my case the option(second console.log) is the same as options(), i mean it contains again inside price and configurable_variation.